# UWP Bluetooth RfComm - System.Exception

Tags: c#, xamarin, uwp, bluetooth, rfcomm

I am trying to connect Server (UWP) to Client (UWP). I have written all the code, but when the server app is running it shows this exception after few seconds at this line:

```
await socketListener.BindServiceNameAsync(rfcommProvider.ServiceId.AsString());
```

**System.Exception: 'An operation on a socket could not be performed because the system lacked sufficient buffer space or because a queue was full.**

I have tried looking on internet but couldn't find any solution.

Comment: I tested with official code [sample](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/BluetoothRfcommChat/cs/Scenario2_ChatServer.xaml.cs#L83) and we could not reproduce this issue, and I found it used `BindServiceNameAsync(rfcommProvider.ServiceId.AsString() ,SocketProtectionLevel.BluetoothEncryptionAllowNullAuthentication)`, could you try to edit your method to above, or share a mini sample that could reproduce this for us.

Comment: It was an issue at my end, the function was being called again and again.

Comment: Could you share a demo for us, it's helpful to find the problem quickly.